# UITextField has trailing the whitespace after secureTextEntry toggle

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to toggle the password text field, but I am facing a problem of  white space at right side of text field.

//Eye button action.

```
@IBAction func btnEyePassword(sender: AnyObject)
{
    //If password text is secure.
    if (self.passrordText.secureTextEntry == true)
    {           
        self.passrordText.secureTextEntry = false         
    }

    else
    {
       self.passrordText.secureTextEntry = true          
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: I am trying to toggle the password text field.

When first secureTextEntry == false 

It is showing white space 
I don't know why it is showing white space at right side of text field.

Comment: try using textfield delegate method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Swift 4** solution

```
func togglePasswordVisibility() {
        password.isSecureTextEntry = !password.isSecureTextEntry
        if let textRange = password.textRange(from: password.beginningOfDocument, to: password.endOfDocument) {
            password.replace(textRange, withText: password.text!)
        }
    }
```

You don't need extra if statement for simple toggle isSecureTextEntry property, but you should replace text this way to force UITextField recalculate text width to avoid extra space.

**UPDATE**

**Swift 4.2**

Instead of

```
password.isSecureTextEntry = !password.isSecureTextEntry
```

you can do this

```
password.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry, in both cases when you print your textField.text your data will be same, there would not be white space.

Check with `print(self.passrordText.text)`

Declare `var str : String = ""`

```
@IBAction func btnEyePassword(sender: AnyObject)
{
    //If password text is secure.
    if (self.passrordText.secureTextEntry == true)
    {           
        self.passrordText.secureTextEntry = false         
        self.passrordText.text = ""
        self.passrordText.text = str
        print(self.passrordText.text)
    }

    else
    {
       self.passrordText.secureTextEntry = true          
       str = self.passrordText.text!
       print(self.passrordText.text)
    }
}
```

This happens because of space consumption, "W" keeps much space while "i" keep lesser space.

Comment: But requirement is like that i don't want white space.
In other applications it is fine means no white space come.

I know data will be same but i have to remove that space.

Comment: Hi @Hasya 
We can edit code when self.passrordText.secureTextEntry == true

  If self.passrordText.secureTextEntry == false conditoin then  '*' is start from beginning .

Thanks